# npm install bcrypt failed

Tags: node.js, npm, bcrypt

I tried to install bcrypt to my Node JS project, but it went wrong.

I am using NodeJS version 4.5.0 and npm 3.10.7.

My operating system is Windows 10 anniversary 64 bit.

Here is error in CMD:

```
C:\Users\kim\Documents\college\Skripsi\jti-test\node_modules\bcrypt>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Users\kim\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "" rebuild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
TRACKER : error TRK0005: Failed to locate: "CL.exe". The system cannot find the
 file specified. [C:\Users\kim\Documents\college\Skripsi\jti-test\node_mo
dules\bcrypt\build\bcrypt_lib.vcxproj]


gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Users\kim\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.14393
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\kim\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\kim\Documents\college\Skripsi\jti-test\node_modules\bcrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v4.5.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\kim\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "bcrypt" "--save"
npm ERR! node v4.5.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.7
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! bcrypt@0.8.7 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@0.8.7 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the bcrypt package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs bcrypt
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls bcrypt
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\kim\Documents\college\Skripsi\jti-test\npm-debug.log
```

This is the full log file: [link](https://jpst.it/NDuy)

Comment: It would be nice if you could give some of the relevant parts of the log file in the question itself.

Comment: okay, I will insert it

Comment: My guess (without seeing the relevant console output that comes before what you're currently showing) is that you do not have the (correct) build tools installed to be able to compile addons. If so, you might try [this module](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/windows-build-tools) to make it easy to install the necessary tools. If that doesn't work for some reason, there is always VC Express.

Comment: I already installed VC express both 2013 and community 2015

Comment: Can you post the actual console output though? That's where the actual error will be, not in the log file unfortunately.

Comment: @mscdex Okay, I already updated the post

Comment: There's an alternative implementation of `bcrypt`, [`bcryptjs`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcryptjs), that's written in native JS and thus won't have these problems. It is, however, slower than `bcrypt` (since it's JavaScript, not C++), but if you're having trouble, it should be a good alternative.

Comment: It's not finding the linker. You might re-opening the command prompt window and/or specifying an explicit msvs version like: `npm install bcrypt --msvs_version=2015`. Otherwise, try using the `windows-build-tools` module I linked to earlier.

Comment: @mscdex Okay, I already installed it.
But when I installed it, there were some warning in CMD.

I pasted the warning here [link](http://pastebin.com/rxDEg6sd).
Is it dangerous?

Comment: Btw I still got error after installed windows-build-tools.

Here is error from my cmd: [link](http://pastebin.com/ZXAApTyV)